# Using Bitrise, is it possible to create custom variable substitutions in an `info.plist` file?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, environment-variables, plist, bitrise

I've noticed that inside `info.plist` there are some strings that use a notation that looks like variable substitutions (e.g. `$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)`).

Does anyone know if it's possible to create custom substitutions and store those values as Secrets in Bitrise?

A perfect example for this use case is to externalize Facebook App ID and Secrets.

Here is what I'd like to be able to do ...

```xml
    ...
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>$(FACEBOOK_APP_ID)</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>$(FACEBOOK_APP_NAME)</string>
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can store Secrete Environment Variables. 
From your dashboard, select your app -> Workflow -> Secrets.
several notes regarding secrets:

1. Secrets are not exposed in the bitrise.yml
2. Secrets are encrypted
3. In alignment with best practices, Bitrise discourages exposing secrets in PRs